# Can't create and run new python file in Komodo

Tags: python, python-3.x, komodo

I recently installed Komodo Editor to write some Python 3 code. I can open the files provided by instructor, however cannot create and run my own files.

When I try to run them, I get the following "env. (file directory) ": Permission denied".

How to create and run new Python programs in Komodo editor?

Comment: Mac is a Unix Fork, therefore specific permissions need to be set for files using the terminal. This can be done by going to the correct location in your directory and employing the "chmod" command. To solve this problem I used "chmod 700 file_name" in the proper terminal.

Answer (score 2):

you can check the permissions of the file by using the command in terminal ls -l "(file directory)/filename.py" if it is missing the x in rwx like mine was, you can reset it by using chmod 700 "file directory/filename.py" 
or do:
chmod +x "file directory/filename.py"